# How to Use an AnimatableVector for Simple 2D Plotting

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui, core-animation

My Swift macOS app renders a simple 2D plot of a one-dimensional array (representing an audio spectrum) provided every 100 milliseconds.  The resultant visualization at 10 frames per second appears very jerky.  I want to animate this plot such that the code generates 5 intermediate spectra between each spectrum of real data to bring the frame rate up to 60 fps.

My understanding is that declaring the one-dimensional array as an AnimatableVector should accomplish this.  But all articles I've seen (for example, [here](https://betterprogramming.pub/swiftui-advanced-animation-morphing-shapes-239a42200181) and [here](https://swiftwithmajid.com/2020/06/17/the-magic-of-animatable-values-in-swiftui/)) use this to animate shapes.  My task involves just an array of Floats, so it should be even easier.  I can get it to render the successive plots, but I can't get it to animate them.  Here's a Minimal Reproducible Example:

First is a DataSource class to generate a vector of 16 Floats every half-second:

```
class DataSource: ObservableObject {

    static let dataSource = DataSource()
    
    @Published var vector: AnimatableVector = AnimatableVector.zero

    init() {
        vector = generateData()
        
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.5, repeats: true) { _ in
            self.vector = self.generateData()
        }
    }

    func generateData() -> AnimatableVector {
        var points = Array.init(repeating: Float.zero, count: 16)
        for i in 0 ..< 16 {
            points[i] = Float.random(in: 0.0 ... 1.0)
        }
        return AnimatableVector(values: points)
    }
}
```

My ContentView struct simply calls my PlotView struct:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var dataSource: DataSource

    var body: some View {
        PlotView()
    }
}
```

Finally, my PlotView View does the actual rendering:

```
struct PlotView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var dataSource: DataSource
    
    var animatableData: AnimatableVector {
        get { return dataSource.vector }
        set { dataSource.vector = newValue }
    }

    var body: some View {
        Canvas { context, size in
            let width: Double  = size.width
            let height: Double = size.height
            var x: Double = 0.0
            var y: Double = 0.0
            
            var path = Path()
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x:0.0, y:height-height*Double(animatableData[0]) ) )

            for i in 1 ..< 16 {
                x = width * Double(i) / Double(15)
                y = height - height * Double( animatableData[i] )
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: y))
            }

            context.stroke( path,
                            with: .color( Color(red: 1.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0) ),
                            lineWidth: 2.0 )
        }
        .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.2), value: animatableData)
    }
}
```

In order to build and run this project, you'll need the AnimatableVector struct from Majid [(here)](https://gist.github.com/mecid/18a80b18cc9670eef1d8667cf8c886bd):

The complete source code for this Minimal Reproducible Example is posted as an Xcode project titled "AnimatedVectorTest" on GitHub [(here)](https://github.com/Keith-43/AnimatedVectorTest).

The plot renders fine, but the animation is not working.  Perhaps I've put the `.animation()` modifier in the wrong place, or perhaps I'm using the wrong value in it.  This looks like a valuable technique, but I need help in the appropriate syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the above project to work.  Simply replace the PlotView View with

```
struct PlotView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var dataSource: DataSource
    public var body: some View {
        PlotShape(vector: dataSource.vector)
            .stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 2)
            .animation(Animation.linear(duration:0.49),value:dataSource.vector)
    }
}
```

and the PlotShape Shape

```
struct PlotShape: Shape {
    var vector: AnimatableVector
    
    public var animatableData: AnimatableVector {
        get { vector }
        set { vector = newValue }
    }
    
    public func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var x: Double = 0.0
        var y: Double = 0.0
 
        var path = Path()
        path.move(to:CGPoint(x:0.0, y:rect.height-rect.height*Double(animatableData[0]) ) )

        for i in 1 ..< vector.count {
            x = rect.width * Double(i) / Double(vector.count - 1)
            y = rect.height - rect.height * Double( vector[i] )
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: y))
        }
        return path
    }
}
```

The complete source code for this example is posted as an Xcode project titled "AnimatableVectorDemo" on GitHub [(here)](https://github.com/Keith-43/AnimatableVectorDemo)

As I indicated in my question, I was seeking a solution that encapsulated the path and the AnimatableVector all inside the View without the need for a separate Shape, but perhaps this is not possible.